# Find Number Of Roots of Equation $11^x + 13^x + 17^x =19^x $

Tags: real-analysis, roots, real-numbers

The Equation
$11^x + 13^x + 17^x =19^x  $

Has

1. No Real Roots
2. Only One Real Roots
3. Exactly Two Real Roots
4. More than Two Real Roots

What I have done is

The function $f(x)=11^x + 13^x + 17^x -19^x  $ is strictly increasing and being always positive it have no roots

Comment: Why do you think your function is always positive?  Consider $19^x((11/19)^x+(13/19)^x+(17/19)^x-1)$

Comment: by a numerical method we get $$x\approx 3.87479542374103393179$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. How does this answer the question which is **how many roots ?** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid your answer is wrong.

One way to see that is consider the function

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{11}{19}\right)^x+\left(\frac{13}{19}\right)^x+\left(\frac{17}{19}\right)^x-1$$

is strictly decreasing and $f(-\infty)=\infty$, $f(\infty)=-1$.

So there is only ONE real root.

Comment: You've shown that OPs choice 1, No Real Roots is false.  But probably need something more to eliminate the other choices, no?

Comment: @sharding4: Nope. The function is strictly decreasing. That is enough to guarantee only one solution.

Comment: And in fact exactly one solution by the intermediate value theorem and continuity.

Comment: My bad.  You're correct.  OP's f(x) is not strictly decreasing, but yours is!

Answer (score 0):

Define, $f(x) = \big(\frac{11}{19}\big)^x + \big(\frac{13}{19}\big)^x + \big(\frac{17}{19}\big)^x - 1$. Clearly $f$ is decreasing continuous function on whole $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $f$ can have **at most one zero**. See that $f(1) = \big(\frac{11}{19}\big) + \big(\frac{13}{19}\big) + \big(\frac{17}{19}\big) - 1 > 0$ and for any sufficiently large $a\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(a) = \big(\frac{11}{19}\big)^a + \big(\frac{13}{19}\big)^a + \big(\frac{17}{19}\big)^a - 1 < 0$. Hence, by **intermediate value theorem**, there exists **at least one zero** in the interval $(1, a)$. Thus, $f$ has **exactly one zero**.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x$. Then $f(3)=1582>0$, $f(4)=-3589<0.$ By Intermediate-value theorem $f(x)=0$ has at least one root in $(3,4)$. Let $x_0$ be that root.

Suppose that $x_0+\epsilon$ is another root. Let $\epsilon >0.$ Then
$$19^{x_0+\epsilon}=11^{x_0+\epsilon}+13^{x_0+\epsilon}+17^{x_0+\epsilon}<
(11^{x_0}+13^{x_0}+17^{x_0})19^{\epsilon}=19^{x_0+\epsilon}$$
with contradiction. Similarly, for $\epsilon<0$ case we can reach a contradiction. So there is one root.

Answer (score -2):

Let y= f(x)= (11÷19)^x+(13÷19)^x+(17÷19)^x-1.
When we put x=0 then  y=2 and when x->infinity then  y->-1 so graph of f(x) cuts the x axis. Hence it has atleast one real root. So option 1 is wrong.
Also f'(x)<0 for all x
Let us suppose that f(x) has two real roots a,b such that   f(a)=0 and f(b)=0. So f:[a,b]->R is continuous in [a,b] and differentiable in (a,b) then by mean value theorem, there exist c in (a,b) such that 
(f(b)-f(a))=(b-a)f'(c) => (b-a)f'(x)=0 but f'(x)<0 for all x. Hence a=b. So f(x) has only one real root.