# How to find a real solution

Tags: real-analysis

Here it is given that the equation $11^x+13^x+17^x-19^x=0$ has only one real root. How can I show it? Please someone give some hints..

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2368799/10063

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;\displaystyle \left(\frac{11}{19}\right)^x+\left(\frac{13}{19}\right)^x+\left(\frac{17}{19}\right)^x\;$ is strictly decreasing, thus injective.