# Rolle's theorem with a supplementary condition

Tags: roots

I have to find the types of roots (i.e real or complex) of the equation $$ 11^x + 13^x+ 17^x -19^x = 0 \dots (1) $$

If $$ f(x) = 11^x + 13^x+ 17^x -19^x = 0 $$ , then obviously $ f'(x)= 0 $ has a 0 solution, and indeed every derivative of $f(x)$ has a  0 solution.

In this context a question arises in my mind : *if all the conditions of Rolle's Theorem are satisfied for a function $g(x) $ in $[a,b]$, and in addition if $g'(c)=0$ ,then is it necessary that $c$ lies between $a$ and $b$ ?*

If it's true, then we can conclude that $f(x)=0 $
has more than 2 real roots right?

Any insight ? Thank you.

Comment: i have found only one real solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2328758/254075), also cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2343196/254075)

Comment: What about the result I asked for in the question ? @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: The real roots of this equation have been asked about previously.  However this Question also asks about an interpretation of Rolle's Thm., which muddles the issue somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if all the conditions of Rolle's Theorem are satisfied for a function $g(x) $ in $[a,b]$, and in addition if $g'(c)=0$ ,then is it necessary that $c$ lies between $a$ and $b$ ?*

No, not at all. Consider for example, $g(x)=\sin(x)$ with $a=0$, $b=\pi$, and $c=\frac32\pi$.

Or (if you mean "strictly between $a$ and $b$"), consider $g(x)=\sin^2(x)$ with $a=0$ and $b=c=\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexamples ! @HenningMakholm.

Comment: This is a good example, but the larger point is that Rolle's Thm. assumes nothing about the function $f (x)$ outside the closed interval $[a,b]$, and cannot conclude anything about $f(x)$ outside the interval.